# SammyJS Index Run

Tags: javascript, url-routing, sammy.js

I'm using Sammy to handle routing in a single-page app. It recently became important that simply navigating to hostname/ isn't the same as navigating to hostname/#!/. I could do app.run("#!/"), but then I can't start the app from other routes. Is there a way I can get a user navigating to my app by typing in the URL to trigger the index route without them having to type '#!/', but at the same time will let them go to other routes if they type those in directly (or more likely, follow links)? This seems like a really common use case for Sammy, so maybe the answer is obvious, but I didn't really know what to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of your question but if I got it right you are looking for a custom "trigger". If you look here -> http://sammyjs.org/docs/events they describe how you can add your own events. So if you listen to a specific event you can trigger you custom binding and even redirect them if necessary. Hope it answered your question :)